# Downloading URL To file... Not returning JSON data but Login HTML instead

Tags: python, json, authentication, cookies, http-headers

I am writing a web scraping application. When I enter the URL directly into a browser, it displays the JSON data I want.
However, if I use Python's request lib, or `URLDownloadToFile` in C++, it simply downloads the html for the login page.

The site I am trying to scrape it from (DraftKings.com) requires a login. The other sites I scrape from don't.
I am 100% sure this is related, since if I paste the url when I am logged out, I get the login page, rather than the JSON data. Once I log in, if I paste the URL again, I get the JSON data again.

The thing is that if I remain logged in, and then use the Python script or C++ app to download the JSON data, as mentioned.... it downloads the Login HTML.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Your Python program also needs to log in... You probably have to POST username/password to that login form, then retrieve a session cookie and attach that to all subsequent requests.

Comment: Use your browser developer tool to monitor a login process and find the requests you need to make.

Comment: Yeah. I know how to monitor, using Firefox dev tools, but my knowledge of what to extract what I need and how to make the POST is not good. If it will help, here is the URL "https://www.draftkings.com/mycontests/history?sortField=ContestEndDate&sortOrder=Desc&daysHistory=30&searchTerm=&page=1&pageSize=50".

Comment: Logins work via **cookies**. You'll need to set the right cookies in your requests. Analyse the requests that are happening again with that in mind and figure it out yourself. We can't help you a whole lot here, unless you have a specific technical question.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't ask us to help with an activity that **violates the terms of service** of the site you are trying to (ab-)use:

> - Using automated means (including but not limited to harvesting bots, robots, parser, spiders or screen scrapers) to obtain, collect or access any information on the Website or of any User for any purpose.

Even if that kind of usage were allowed, the answer would be boring:

You'd need to **implement the login functionality in your scraper**.